# How to check if sqlite db file exists in directory and also check if a table exists using python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to append records to a sqlite db file in a table, first checking if the db file exists and then checking if the table exists. If not create the db and table file dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using sqlite3 library, in that if you use connect method it will do exactly what you want.find the db or else create it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on to answer by @Umang, you could check for the table's existence using a query as `SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';`.

Answer (score 0):

What you typically do is simply:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...''')
```

If `example.db` exists, it'll be used, otherwise it'll be created.
If the table already exists, the `CREATE TABLE` command will do nothing, otherwise it'll create the table. Done.